# How to return images sequentially inside a "for loop"?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, view

My view displays collections from four different tables. `$redtable` is my longest collection.

```xml
@for ($i = 0; $counter < $redtable->count(); $i++)
    <div>
        {{ $red->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $blue->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $gray->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
    <div>
@endfor
```

My image table:

```
+----+------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| id | image                              | imageable_type          | imageable_id |
+----+------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | /path/redtable/image.png           | App\Models\Red          |            1 |
|  2 | /path/greentable/image.png         | App\Models\Green        |            1 |
|  3 | /path/blue/image1.png              | App\Models\Blue         |            1 |
|  4 | /path/blue/image2.png              | App\Models\Blue         |            1 |
|  5 | /path/blue/image3.png              | App\Models\Blue         |            1 |
|  6 | /path/blue/image4.png              | App\Models\Blue         |            1 |
|  7 | /path/blue/image5.png              | App\Models\Blue         |            1 |
|  8 | /path/gray/image.png               | App\Models\Gray         |            2 |
+----+------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

My Controller:

```php
class ColorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $red = \App\Models\Red::with('polymorphicRelationship')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $green = \App\Models\Green::with('polymorphicRelationship')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $blue = \App\Models\Blue::with('polymorphicRelationship')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $gray = \App\Models\Gray::with('polymorphicRelationship')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        
        return view('home.colors', [
            'red' => $red,
            'green' => $green,
            'blue' => $blue,
            'gray' => $gray
        ]);
    }
```

How to display the images of the "Model Blue" table in the view.

I did a test using `$picture->first()?->polymorphicRelationship()->first()->image`, but it only displays the image of the first line of the table.

```xml
@for ($i = 0; $counter < $red->count(); $i++)
    <div class="general">
        {{ $red->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $blue->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        <div class="slide">
            <!-- First slide image -->
            {{ $blue->polymorphicRelationship->image1 }}
            <!-- Second slide image -->
            {{ $blue->polymorphicRelationship->image1 }}
            <!-- Third slide image -->
            {{ $blue->polymorphicRelationship->image1 }}
            <!-- Fourth slide image -->
            {{ $blue->polymorphicRelationship->image1 }}
            <!-- Fifth slide image -->
            {{ $blue->polymorphicRelationship->image1 }}
        </div>
        {{ $graytable->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
    </div>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming the relationship is defined as a [polymorphic one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations), you can just add another loop.

Also you can replace `slice($i, 1)->first()` with `get($i)`.

```xml
@for ($i = 0; $counter < $red->count(); $i++)
    <div class="general">
        {{ $red->get($i)?->content }}
        {{ $green->get($i)?->content }}
        {{ $blue->get($i)?->content }}
        <div class="slide">
            @foreach ($blue->polymorphicRelationship as $image)
                {{ $image->image }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {{ $graytable->get($i)?->content }}
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: I did the test and it worked, it returns all 5 images. All the images on the slides on the page go through at the same time, but at least it returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think to display the images of the Blue table in the view sequentially, you need to retrieve the images for each row of the Blue table separately. One way to do this is to loop through the rows of the Blue table along with the other tables and display the images of each row in a separate slide.

```php
@for ($i = 0; $i < $red->count(); $i++)
    <div class="general">
        {{ $red->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        {{ $green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
        @if ($i < $blue->count())
            <div class="slide">
                @foreach ($blue[$i]->polymorphicRelationship->images as $image)
                    <img src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="">
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
        {{ $gray->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked. As with the solution proposed by IGP, all 5 images returned. Now I'm going to try to make each <div> animate the slides separately. Thanks!